# Confusion about using malloc/calloc pointer to hold the return value of realloc

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, realloc

Someone said that using the original malloc()/calloc() pointer as the variable that holds the return value of realloc() is wrong. Here is an example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
    int *malloc_ptr = malloc(5 * sizeof(int));
    malloc_ptr = realloc(malloc_ptr, 10 * sizeof(int));


    return 0;
}
```

Their reasoning was that if realloc() failed it would return NULL thus making malloc_ptr == NULL. That would make you lose access to the memory you requested with malloc(). Their solution was to do this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
    int *malloc_ptr = malloc(5 * sizeof(int));
    int *realloc_ptr = realloc(malloc_ptr, 10 * sizeof(int));

    if (realloc_ptr == NULL) {
        // Whatever you want to do
    } else
        malloc_ptr = realloc_ptr;


    return 0;
}
```

However if they are correct doesn't that mean that some software that uses the malloc pointer as the holder of realloc() could be incorrect because I've seen a lot of people use the malloc()/calloc() pointer as the variable that holds the return value of realloc(). Is this true?

Comment: A lot of people just don't bother to care about what happens if there is not enough memory. A lot of programs just crash if there is not enough memory.

Comment: @user253751 Is this bug easy to debug?

Comment: not sure what you mean. The program will crash when it does *malloc_ptr if malloc_ptr is null

Comment: @user253751 No the if statement is to check if realloc_ptr is null. That way I know if I can make malloc_ptr point to the reallocated block of memory.

Comment: Your understanding is correct. Second example shows correct `realloc` handling, but, <snip>, misses `malloc` return value check. However, I didn't understood - what is your question exactly?

Comment: But then you asked about "this bug". The second program doesn't have a bug so I assume you are talking about the first one. And the answer is if malloc_ptr is null then *malloc_ptr will crash.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs I wanted to verify if what the person said is correct. I have seen a lot of people use the malloc_ptr as the holder for the return value of realloc().

Comment: @user253751 Sorry if I was vague. So the first program will crash? Is the second one what I should do when I use realloc()?

Comment: @user20598969 [`man realloc`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc) clearly states the possible return values, and people need to stick to a good practice of checking all the return values.

Comment: the first program won't crash because there is nothing in the program that would make it crash. But real programs don't just allocate memory for no reason. They allocate memory and then store data in the memory. And when they try to store data in the null pointer they will crash.

Comment: @user253751 *the first program won't crash*. I'd say: the first program won't *usually* crash.

Comment: @user253751  I was just providing an example. Thanks

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs why would it ever crash? the pointer is not used

Comment: @user253751 Well, yes. But this is a minimal example, normally there's something in between malloc and realloc, right?

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs neither malloc nor realloc crashes if you run out of memory

Comment: @user253751 check my edited comment above. In this particular example, of course, won't crash.

Comment: Side note: The programme *likely* crashes on dereferencing the null pointer – does so on most operating systems including any posix (SIGSEGV) or windows. There are architectures where worse can occur, e.g. some microcontrollers use address `0` as entry point (first thing they execute after startup) – if you overwrite this your MCU in best case renders unstartable or in worst case starts doing harmful stuff...

Comment: "doesn't that mean that some software could be incorrect because" Software is incorrect for all sorts of reasons. Why would this reason be special?

Comment: @Gerhardh Sorry I should have specified software that use the malloc pointer as the holder of the return value of realloc(). Such a program would likely crash if the null pointer would be dereferenced as Aconcagua stated. (I edited the question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [`man realloc`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc), this would be correct way of `realloc` handling:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int *malloc_ptr = malloc(5 * sizeof(int));

    if (malloc_ptr == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate memory\n");
        /* here goes error handling */
    }

    /* ... */

    int *realloc_ptr = realloc(malloc_ptr, 10 * sizeof(int));

    if (realloc_ptr == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not reallocate memory, keeping the old allocated block\n");
        /* here goes error handling */
    } else {
        malloc_ptr = realloc_ptr;
    }

    /* ... */

    free(malloc_ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So is it safe to assume malloc_ptr remains unchanged and the data that was there is 'unfreed' if realloc() returns NULL?

Comment: @SimonGoater: Yes, documentation states: *If realloc() fails the original block is left untouched; it is not freed or moved.*